# Django: Get Months since a certain datetime

Tags: python, django, django-models, time

I'm trying to get the number of months since a model is created.

My Model looks like this:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    plan_type = models.IntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now i want to make a method that returns the number of months since the date_created.
Tanks for any help :D

Comment: You want to get number of month. Suppose for today datetime it will return 4?

Comment: No, when i create the model it also sets the date_created. Let's say i created it in fabruary. Now i want no know how the number of months since that date. In this excample 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing dates creates a `datetime.timedelta` object that you can use to get the difference between dates.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now    


delta: timedelta = now() - plan.date_created
delta.days  # Number of days between dates.
```

You can then use that value to convert it to months or years.

The other alternative would be a bit more complicated, but since `DateTimeField` returns a `datetime.datetime` object, you can also access the month number of the original date and compare it against todays date.

e.g.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

month_diff = now().month - plan.date_created.month
```

The problem with the second alternative is that you then have to take into account if they are the same year or not, and if they are not you then have to take that into account when you get the month difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a property in your model like

```
from django.utils import timezone
class Plan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    @property
    def get_month(self):
        return self.date_created.month - timezone.now().month
```

Then you can get the value like this

```
>>> Plan.objects.first().get_month
4
```

Comment: This gives the month of the created date. Not how many months since the created date.

Comment: Your edit only works when dates are within the same year.